# Problem logging utf-8 strings in MySQL from Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to log a string sent from client side to MySQL database from a Java application. The string sent from client is UTF-8 encoded. I have confirmed this as I have taken packet traces using tool like wireshark. The string that the client sends are 3 characters which are  Latin OE (0xc593), and beta (0xc39f), Euro sign (0xE2 0x82 0xAC). I am using prepared statement way of setstring to log the string into database. The table is created with support for utf-8 char encoding. Now, when I see the logged string in database I find this

```
select hex(message) from table1

C385 C293 C383 C29F C3A2 C282 C2AC
```

Seems like something is changing the string in the middle. Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode.html),

> Client applications that need to
>   communicate with the server using
>   Unicode should set the client
>   character set accordingly; for
>   example, by issuing a SET NAMES 'utf8'
>   statement.

You should also check the [character_set_client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_client) and [character_set_connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_character_set_connection) system variables to get an idea of how MySQL is attempting to interpret your string.

You can check the collation that individual tables are using by running the `SHOW TABLE STATUS IN database` query, as well.

Hopefully that will give you a clearer picture of exactly what the MySQL server is trying to do with the strings you're sending from the client.  Reading up in [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode.html) should be enlightening, as well.

Good luck :-)